# code.google.com/p/go.crypto/pbkdf2 file not found?

Tags: go, mercurial

I want to make juju charm-store server, but when I try to build/install it gives me this error:

`imports code.google.com/p/go.crypto/pbkdf2: exec: "hg": executable file not found`

The charm-store repository can be found [here](https://github.com/sajith4u/charmstore) (github).

I also tried to get the package using the following command but it failed:

`go get -u -v -t github.com/juju/charmstore/..`.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means one of the dependencies (here [`code.google.com/p/go.crypto/pbkdf2`](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/checkout?repo=crypto)) is in a [Mercurial repo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial).

You need to [install Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads) in order for `go get` or the `make` to complete the process.
For instance, [on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mercurial):

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial meld
```

---

Note: go 1.4 (Q4 2014) will [rename that package](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-announce/eD8dh3T9yyA) in **`golang.org/x/crypto`**.

Comment: Thanks for your help.But this time again failed.Now i got this error.# github.com/juju/charmstore/src/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/sasl
src/github.com/juju/charmstore/src/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/sasl/sasl.go:12:24: fatal error: sasl/sasl.h: No such file or directory
 // #include <sasl/sasl.h>

Comment: @Sajith4U that's completely different: your question was about hg. I have answered that question.

Comment: Thanks for your help.i know it is regarding hg.Sorry to interrupt you.

Comment: `apt-get install libsasl2-dev` should fix the error.

Comment: Thanks Nick.Now i got another issue.Do you familiar with this problem.http://askubuntu.com/questions/522721/juju-charmstore-server-install-failed